# View file path in a file manager as Android intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Just so you know, I've already checked both the Android developer documentation and [OpenIntents](http://www.openintents.org/), without finding an answer.  I might easily have missed something, though.

Is there an intent action for viewing a file path in a file manager?  There seems to be little in the way of standardisation among Android file manager apps. I don't want any unusual behaviour when the intent is carried out, and if no file manager is installed it should do nothing, rather than trying to action the file path in some other way.

My initial research suggests this probably isn't currently possible, but I thought I'd see if anyone knew better.  They usually do.

**Edited to clarify:** I'm not looking for a file picker.  I already have a file path and want to open it for browsing in a file manager/file browser, if and only if there is one installed on the device.

Answer (score 11):

I have the following ...

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("text/csv");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getText(R.string.select_file)),1);
```

and then onActivityResult()

```
        currFileURI = data.getData();
        filename_editText.setText(currFileURI.getPath());
```

UPDATE: SOLUTION:

```
public static boolean isUriAvailable(Context context, String uri) {
    Intent test = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    return context.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(test, 0) != null;
}
```

Comment: That looks like a file picker, which isn't really what I'm after.  I want to say to the system "here's a file path; open this in a file manager app (like eFile or AndExplorer or whatever), or if you don't have a file manager installed, do nothing".

Comment: You are correct.  That's exactly what it does.  I was merely hoping that it would give you a hint toward your answer.  Sorry if it's not helpful.  I'll see if I can pass in a path and have the file manager open.  You can, of course, start the filemanager without asking for anything in return.

Comment: Sorry.  I judged your response a bit hastily, and it's almost certainly my own ignorance that's getting in the way.  I read your above code as prompting a user for their choice of application to pick a CSV file.  You're suggesting that I can create an intent that would allow a user to select an application that _could_ pick the type of file, and then just open the application.  Right?

Comment: Seemingly, but I've never tried it :)  Your assumption about what my code does is 100% correct.  I don't have my development environment with me at the office so I can't try what I'm proposing, but I should think you could just open the intent without any expectation of getting anything in return.  The next feat is opening to a specific path.  I think that all sounds very reasonable.

Comment: Well, thank you.  That's certainly a much more promising avenue than my own doom-mongering about it not being possible :-)  I'll let you know how it goes.