# Filter .xml file in the File Explorer

Tags: android, xml, file, filtering

i wanted to show only .xml files to user which is currently present in the sd card.i try the following but it shows all files in my sdcard including directories

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("text/xml");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select XML File"), SelectXMLFILE);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626433/android-browse-file-intent-with-defined-extension `There is no guarantee that any "file manager" will honor your MIME type; they may elect to display all files anyway`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code and manipulate it according to your needs

```
File sdcardPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +"/SomeFolder");

List<String> list;
list = new ArrayList<String>();
list=sdcardPath.listFiles();
```

Now loop through the list and check each file name and apply endWith("xml"); function on the items to get all xml files. Hope it works.

Loop in it like that

```
List<String> XMLFiles= new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<=list.size(); i++)
{
   XMLFiles.add(list.get(i).endsWith("xml"));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have samsung galaxy s3 with android 4.1.2. My internal phone memory is named sdcard0 and my external card extSdCard.

```
 Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

So the above returns the path of sdcard0 which is internal phone memory

In such cases to get the actual path you can use the below

```
String externalpath = new String();
String internalpath = new String();

public  void getExternalMounts() {
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
try  
{
Process proc = runtime.exec("mount");
InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
String line;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
if (line.contains("secure")) continue;
if (line.contains("asec")) continue;

if (line.contains("fat")) {//external card
String columns[] = line.split(" ");
if (columns != null && columns.length > 1) {
    externalpath = externalpath.concat("*" + columns[1] + "\n");
}
} 
else if (line.contains("fuse")) {//internal storage
String columns[] = line.split(" ");
if (columns != null && columns.length > 1) {
    internalpath = internalpath.concat(columns[1] + "\n");
}
}
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 e.printStackTrace();
}
 System.out.println("Path  of sd card external............"+externalpath);
 System.out.println("Path  of internal memory............"+internalpath); 
}
```

Once you get the path.

```
File dir= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
//Instead of android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() you can use internalpath or externalpath
```

Then call

```
walkdir(dir);

ArrayList<String> filepath= new ArrayList<String>();//contains list of all files ending with .xml

public void walkdir(File dir) {
String xmlPattern = ".xml";

File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();

if (listFile != null) {
for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

    if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
        walkdir(listFile[i]);
    } else {
      if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(xmlPattern)){
          //Do what ever u want
          filepath.add( listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
       }
     }
    }
   }    
  }
```

Comment: @user2240031 did u try the above?