# How to set a file extension?

Tags: android, android-studio, storage, file-manager

how to set a file extension in this code ?
example i set this extension ".apk" then when appear the file manager that only can see a file is this extension ".apk"

```
package com.devkun;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


public class Kirigaya extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.toyi);

    }

    public void Importf(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("file/*");
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this:

[android browse file intent with defined extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626433/android-browse-file-intent-with-defined-extension)

It is not available to define a file extension!