# How to choose only .aar file from file manager in android

Tags: android, kotlin

How to pass the data in intent to show only .arr(firmware) file  from file manager in android

```
val intent = Intent()
 intent.type = "*/*"
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, false)
 intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Firmware File"),111)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

afaik there is [no such mime type](https://www.lifewire.com/file-extensions-and-mime-types-3469109) for your extensions (not sure `aar` or `arr`), so this is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626433/android-browse-file-intent-with-defined-extension). you have to write own file picker or use some common library (e.g. [THIS](https://github.com/DroidNinja/Android-FilePicker)) and filter list with desired file extension (linked lib have `addFileSupport` method). also be aware of [Scoped storage limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)