# Intent-filter to allow other apps to connect to this app for selecting folders

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to use an `Intent` to start an app for selecting a folder.  I've looked at a lot of threads on this and I haven't found any with a solution other that those which have hardcoded references to specific apps like OI.
For example:  `Intent intent = new Intent("org.openintents.action.PICK_DIRECTORY");`

I keep getting these errors probably because my emulator doesn't have the right app on it:

> - //No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=directory:// }
> - //No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=folder:// }
> - //No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://vnd.google-apps.folder }
> - //No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=file:///storage/emulated/0 }
> - //No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT dat=file:///storage/emulated/0 }

I've found several sample apps that do return files or folders.  I guess I'll grab one of them and rewrite it for my usage.  I'd rather make the `Intent` used to start it as generic as possible and not hardcode the name of my app.

What are the pairs of `Intents` and `intent-filters` which I need to add the code to allow connection between some app and my file/folder selector program?

Comment: Have you looked at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923760/how-to-use-intent-for-choosing-file-browser-to-select-file
More specifically the link therein:
https://code.google.com/p/android-file-dialog/

Answer (score 1):

> What are the pairs of Intents and intent-filters which I need to add the code to allow connection between some app and my file/folder selector program?

There are no standards here that I am aware of, other than perhaps `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` for the `*/*` MIME type.

Of your five bulleted attempts, only the fourth one would be considered generally valid:

- The first two use schemes that may not be recognized
- The third is tied to some Google `ContentProvider`
- The fifth is malformed, as `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is to pick by MIME type, not container

You are welcome to try to spearhead the definition of some standards in this space, or do what Aleksander suggests and use a library to provide this capability within your app rather than relying upon outside apps.

Comment: Spearheading is always fun, just a matter of how much time you've got for this project and how much effort you're willing to put in :) If selecting a folder or a file is all you need it shouldn't take much time to just build that into your app rather than using something external to it.

Comment: The question is how to differentiate between asking for a file and asking for a folder.  MIME type of * / * wouldn't say what was wanted.

Comment: @NormR: There are no "folders" in Android, any more than there are in a Web browser.

Comment: @CommonsWare What do you call the "disk" component that holds files?  I'm looking for the path to a place where the program can write a file. I want the user to be able to select that place.

Comment: @NormR: And for that, you are best off rolling your own UI. Like iOS and, as I understand it, newer versions of OS X, OS makers are trying to get away from files-and-directories. Hence, Android does not have a "folder" picker built in.

Comment: How does one get to files that the browser puts in the Download "folder" if there are no folder navigation tools?

Comment: @NormR: Generally, it is the responsibility of the app that downloaded the file to provide means of accessing it. If you happen to be using `DownloadManager`, it will handle that chore for you, by showing a `Notification` upon download completion.

Comment: None of my browsers do anything with what they put in the Download folder.  I'll have to research how to use DownloadManager when using a browser that is downloading a file.  Thanks for the advice.