# How to start file browser app from Android application?

Tags: java, android

I have an App that is started from "share via" menu and get the list of the selected files as an input. Now, what I would like to do is to let the user be able to run file browsing app from my App and then get back the results.

I know for example that I can start phonebook and obtain the choosen contact(s) with following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

So the question is: is there a similar way to run the file browser and to get in return a list of all files selected?

**EDIT:** the "possible duplicated post" is actually only partially similar, as it ask how to start the file manager inside a specific path, and by the way hasn't an accepted answer. What I really need, if it is possible, is to start the file manager (if there is one) to a specific path and then get in return the selected files.

thank you all very much

Cristiano

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use intent for choosing file browser to select file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923760/how-to-use-intent-for-choosing-file-browser-to-select-file)

Comment: selecting multiple files doesn't work on API's lower than 18, so you may need to selected one by one.

Comment: DavidJhons thank you for your comment. Even if only single selection works, how do I start file browser and get back the selected file?