# Choose a text file and then read it on Android Platform

Tags: android, file, android-intent, browser

My android app has a Button widget, wherein I have written the following inside the file `activity_main.xml`, apart from other necessary text.

```
<Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Numbers"
   android:id="@+id/btnBrowse"
   android:onClick="clickButtonBrowse"
 />
```

In the file `MainActivity.java` apart from the other functions, I wrote the following:

```
protected void clickButtonBrowse() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(intent, FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

My idea is to open a file browser, and select a file. I have taken the help from this question [on selecting a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923760/how-to-use-intent-for-choosing-file-browser-to-select-file).

Now I have no idea on the following:

1. How to get the name of the file from the intent, so that I can read it.
2. How is this `FILE_REQUEST_CODE` to be defined? What are the permissible values?

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to startActivityForResult not startActivity, as in the example you were using.
  Then you can:

```
public synchronized void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
        int resultCode, final Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        String filePath = data.getStringExtra(FileDialog.RESULT_PATH);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Where is FileDialog ??

Comment: It is whatever activity you are using to browse the files.  See the details in the link you posted.  It tells you how to get a file.  Whatever you name your copy of that class, substitute for FileDialiog