# How can I get a button to open a specific folder in file explorer while building an Android app?

Tags: android

I'm building an Android app that needs to be able to go thru file explorer and pick a file. as of now, have a button (that doesn't do anything yet) from app > res > menu > main.xml but I need pressing it to take my to the file explorer, from which a user can chose a file that ultimately will be uploaded.

How and where should I code this, both in xml and java? I've looked online, but most Google search results with "file explorer" and "android studio" in the query return posts about people using file explorer on their emulator more than integrating it's use into the app.

perhaps I should've added that I want a menu button to do it, and with the latest dev tools.

edit: here's my logcat file (tho I moved the functionality to a new button instead of a menu drop down and edited out my name and project name).

[click the link to see text from logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWBSU.jpg)

Comment: Here were the top two google results for "java android select file to upload".. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856959/android-file-chooser and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923760/how-to-use-intent-for-choosing-file-browser-to-select-file ... Both of these appear to aid your situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use intent for choosing file browser to select file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923760/how-to-use-intent-for-choosing-file-browser-to-select-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this in the click of button:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_RESULT_CODE);
```

you can set a filter for third-party file browsers. Or you can try to use this file dialog: http://code.google.com/p/android-file-dialog/

Comment: in MainActivity: private void showFileChooser() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("file/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, -1);

        try {
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"), -1);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } & set onClick but app crashes

Comment: pleaseee help me

Comment: send the crash report

Comment: where/how can I find this? I've enabled developer options in my Nexus 5X emulator

Comment: I tried having the button's onClick as showFileChooser[MainActivity] when I did this

Comment: while running u have a logcat running send me the screenshot or report of the errors...

Comment: the logcat stuff is in a photo