# Is there a file explorer service in android?

Tags: android, browser, android-service

i want it to return the selected path as a string,when a browse button is clicked...

```
String cachePath = mContext.getExternalFilesDir("mnt/sdcard").getAbsolutePath() + "/" + file;
```

i want it to use it here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this answer, it has the intent you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5538300/354247